# Google Map API Rectangle Class

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, rectangles, bounds, drawrectangle

I have a draggable rectangle on my map. If the user drags the rectangle into a square shape, I know both sides are equal.  How can I determine the length of one side compared to the other?  I can use getBounds and probably work something out with that but I assume there is an easier way.  I don't need the actual number, I only need to know relative to each other. For example the rectangle is twice as wide as it is high, or three times as high as it is wide.

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: You probably need to use the [Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance)'s `computeDistanceBetween` function

Comment: Thanks Duncan,  I used computeDistanceBetween from the Most Excellent example on your blog at:
[link](https://duncan99.wordpress.com/tag/google-maps-api)

Comment: How can I mark Duncan's answer as accepted? There is no check mark to click on.

Comment: I'll post some code as an answer that you can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a draggable rectangle, you could get its bounds when the user's finished dragging it.  Then you could use the Geometry library to get the length of its sides.  Something like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 90% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map { height: 100% }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: {lat: 51.476706, lng: 0},
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
            bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                {lat: 51.4721885614119, lng: -0.029311180114746094}, 
                {lat: 51.48122299123414, lng: 0.029311180114746094}
            ),
            editable: true,
            map: map
        });

        rectangle.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {            
            var bounds = this.getBounds();

            var proportion = getSideProportions(bounds);

            $('#proportion').text('The width is ' + proportion + ' times the height');
        });
    }

    /* Imagine a rectangle with these corners:
    * A--B
    * |  |
    * C--D
    * PointB = the North-East corner,
    * PointC = the South-West corner
    */
    function getSideProportions(bounds) {
        var PointA, PointB, PointC, NorthEastLatitude, SouthWestLongitude, horizontalDistance, verticalDistance, proportion;

        // get the coordinates for the NE and SW corners
        PointB = bounds.getNorthEast();
        PointC = bounds.getSouthWest();

        // from that, figure out the latitudes and the longitudes
        NorthEastLatitude =  PointB.lat();

        SouthWestLongitude =  PointC.lng();

        PointA = new google.maps.LatLng(NorthEastLatitude, SouthWestLongitude);

        horizontalDistance = getDistance(PointA, PointB);
        verticalDistance = getDistance(PointA, PointC);

        proportion = horizontalDistance / verticalDistance;

        return Math.round(proportion * 10) / 10;
    }

    function getDistance(point1, point2) {
        return google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point1, point2);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="proportion"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ref: https://duncan99.wordpress.com/2013/10/19/google-maps-size/

Comment: Thank You!  Excellent Code.